# ¿Cómo implementar correctamente un radio buttons con react hook form?

Tags: reactjs, radiobutton, radiogroup, react-hook-form

Mi problema es que tengo un formulario en react manejado con **react hook form**, pero por alguna razón **los radio buttons no me funcionan correctamente** cuando utilizo dos o más con el mismo nombre. Lo que pasa es que cuando se solicita que sea requerido y selecciono la primera opción me da error de validación al enviar el formulario, pero si vuelvo a seleccionar la misma opción después del error ya no muestra ningún error y se puede enviar la información.

Mi código es el siguiente:

**Componente para grupo de RadioButtons**

```
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form'

import { classNames } from 'utils'

export default function RadioGroup({ id, title, options, validation }) {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useFormContext()

  return (
    <>
      {title}
      {options.map(({ label, value, readOnly }, i) => (
        <label key={i} className="inline-flex items-center">
          <input
            {...register(id, validation)}
            type="radio"
            value={value}
            readOnly={readOnly}
            className={classNames(
              readOnly
                ? 'bg-gray-100 cursor-not-allowed border-gray-300 focus:border-gray-300'
                : errors[id]
                ? 'border-red-500 focus:border-red-500'
                : 'h-5 w-5 text-blue-600'
            )}
          />
          <span className="ml-2 text-gray-700">{label}</span>
        </label>
      ))}
      <div className="mt-1">
        {errors[id] && errors[id].type === 'required' && (
          <span className="text-xs text-red-500">{`Seleccione una opción`}</span>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Y desde otro componente llamo al de RadioGroup de la siguiente manera:

```
const methods = useForm({ mode: 'onSubmit' })
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors }
  } = methods

<FormProvider {...methods}>
    <form
    onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
    className="w-full space-y-4 p-2"
    >
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1">
            <RadioGroup
                title="Es propio"
                id="isOwn"
                options={[
                    { label: 'Sí', value: '1' },
                    { label: 'No', value: '0' }
                ]}
                validation={{
                    required: true
                }}
            />
        </div>
        <div className="mt-8 w-full">
            <div className="float-right px-4 space-x-2">
                <button
                    className="btn btn-success"
                    type="submit"
                >
                    Guardar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</FormProvider>
```

La parte que genera el problema es la validación de requerido. Si no lleva validación funciona (pero no valida y necesito que lo haga).
Estuve viendo la implementación en la página oficial y ahí parece funcionar bien, pero a mí no.
Incluso hice pruebas agregando los RadioButtons estáticos y siempre sucede el mismo problema.
Agradecería mucho si me pueden ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya logré resolver por medio de un Controller en el componente del RadioGroup.

Quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
import { useFormContext, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'

import { classNames } from 'utils'

export default function RadioGroup({ id, title, options, validation }) {
  const {
    control,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useFormContext()

  return (
    <>
      {title}
      <Controller
        name={id}
        id={id}
        isClearable
        control={control}
        rules={validation}
        render={({ field }) => {
          console.log(field)
          return options.map(({ label, value, readOnly }, i) => (
            <label key={i} className="inline-flex items-center">
              <input
                {...field}
                type="radio"
                value={value}
                checked={field.value === value}
                readOnly={readOnly}
                className={classNames(
                  readOnly
                    ? 'bg-gray-100 cursor-not-allowed border-gray-300 focus:border-gray-300'
                    : errors[id]
                    ? 'border-red-500 focus:border-red-500'
                    : 'h-5 w-5 text-blue-600'
                )}
              />
              <span className="ml-2 text-gray-700">{label}</span>
            </label>
          ))
        }}
      />
      <div className="mt-1">
        {errors[id] && errors[id].type === 'required' && (
          <span className="text-xs text-red-500">{`Seleccione una opción`}</span>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```